# is it possible in multithreading that dictionary return wrong values c#

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I have a c# dictionary in a multithreaded environment. I'm using TryGetValue for reading without lock and in the same moment the dictionary is reorganizing. Is it possible to get a completly different value not related to this key? I mean not just a value that is not up-to-date but a value that is totaly wrong corresponding to a different key.

```
public static bool ChangeKey<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict,
                                       TKey oldKey, TKey newKey)
    {
        TValue value;
        if (!dict.TryGetValue(oldKey, out value))
            return false;

        dict.Remove(oldKey);  // do not change order
        dict[newKey] = value;  // or dict.Add(newKey, value) depending on ur comfort
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What's the implementation you're using? If it's a `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` then no, you can't safely use that between threads without locking.

Comment: Thanks bro, problem solved...Can you tell me how to close or delete this thread ??

Comment: you can't close a question whereas you can accept the answer or you can delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

No, It's not possible to get a different value form dictionary. If TryGetValue returns true, then the value should be correct.

Why not use ConcurrentDictionar? ConcurrentDictionary is a thread-safe dictionary implementation

Answer (score 0):

Used ConcurrentDictionary  as suggested above... This solved my problem..